# Python: can anyone tell me why a while loop i use for invalid operators is not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I understand that when typing an invalid operator for the first time the while loop begins but after I type a valid operator after the loop begins, it doesn't seem to exit out of it.

Is it because I have multiple conditions , since it actually works if I only have one condition?

```py
numb_1 = float(input("Enter the first number:"))
operator = input("Enter an operator:")
numb_2 = float(input("Enter the second number:"))

while operator != ("+") or operator != ("-")  or operator != ("*") or operator != ("/"):
    print("Invalid operator please try again.")
    operator = input("Enter an operator:")

if operator == ("+"):
    print(numb_1 + numb_2)

elif operator == ("-"):
    print(numb_1 - numb_2)

elif operator == ("*"):
    print(numb_1 * numb_2)

elif operator == ("/"):
    print(numb_1 / numb_2)
```

Comment: can you please post your code?

Comment: yes I have just posted it thank you

Comment: You need `and` not `or`... Think what happens if you input `"+"`. The condition `operator != ("-")` is still `True` so the condition holds. You want to check that the input is different than ***all*** operators so you need to use `and`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1):

A little code snippet might help to understand your exact question. An operator is typically something like '+', '-', '/', '%', '*', '&', ... etc. I'm not clear what you mean with an "invalid operator". Since you are referring to a while loop, and expecting it to exit out, I guess you are referring to a 'condition'?

```
while(<condition == true>):
  <do something>
```

Make sure your condition actually once becomes *not* True (False), and your code block should jump out of your while block.

---

**Updating now that the original post has the code.**

The problem is here:

```
operator != ("+") or operator != ("-")  or operator != ("*") or operator != ("/")
```

Since you are using a logical 'or' operator, the moment 1 of these conditions is true, the entire condition is true. See truth table of OR.

Which means... if you enter +, the condition "operator != ("-")" is true... => the while loop condition is true, and you stay in the loop forever.

A better ways would be:

```
operator = input("Enter an operator:")
while operator not in ["+", "-", "*", "/"]:
  print("Invalid operator please try again.")
  operator = input("Enter an operator:")
```

Comment: yes Ive made the condition true once to activate the loop but when I make the condition false it doesnt exit the loop. I wonder if it's because I have multiple conditions since the loop works just fine with one condition.

Comment: Thanks for putting the code. Your problem is that you were checking multiple conditions with a logical or. Which means, the moment 1 condition is true, the entire series of conditions is true. So if someone enters '+', a valid character, your condition ' != '-' ' is true. Hence the condition is still true, and you keep looping!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
numb_1 = float(input("Enter the first number:"))

while True:
    operator = input("Enter an operator:").strip()
    if operator in["+", "-", "/", "*"]:
         break
    else:
        print("Invalid operator please try again.")

numb_2 = float(input("Enter the second number:"))
```

Comment: yes this worked too thank you!

Comment: it's a pleasure, could you please upvote it and if you think so matìrk it as the correct answer?